# print variable-name in Matlab

Tags: matlab, string-formatting, naming-conventions

I have a function in Matlab that has some variables in it.  I need to print out the variable_names (in case of an exception etc.).  I am aware of `inputname` function but it works for input_arguments only.

```
mat = [ 1 2 ; 3 4 ] ;

% disp(['Error in var: ' ??(a)])
% desired ouput: Error in var: mat     (and NOT 1 2 ; 3 4!)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `(a)` supposed to be?

Comment: @gnovice: I think he meant to say `mat` instead of `a`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what could be the use case of this exercise? What I mean is that the variable name is actually known in this state. What prevents from typing `disp('Error in var: mat')`? Do not take this as critisism, but as a question of genuine interest.

Comment: @patrik Not sure about the OP's need for this but I needed this because a library took in the name of a matlab variable as input.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Matlab essentially does not let you do that. However, you can write a helper function to ease your pain in creating output like that:

```
function disp_msg_var(msg, v)
  disp([msg inputname(2)]);
end
```

which you could call like so in your case:

```
disp_msg_var('Error in: ', a);
```

You can read more discussion on the topic on the [Mathworks forum](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/166740)

Additionally, to list all current variables with values you can use the `who` function, but that is not the problem you presented.

Answer (score 17):

```
varname=@(x) inputname(1);
disp(['Error in var: ' varname(mat)])
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm adding another solution to the mix (one-liner):

```
function myFunction()
    mat = [1 2; 3 4];
    disp(['Error in var: ' feval(@(x)inputname(1),mat)])
end
```

Which outputs:

```
Error in var: mat
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print out the variables present in a function, you can use the function [WHO](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/who.html). Here's an example using a simple function `test.m`:

```
function test
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
  varNames = who();
  disp(sprintf('%s ','Variables are:',varNames{:}));
  c = 3;
  d = 4;
  varNames = who();
  disp(sprintf('%s ','Variables are:',varNames{:}));
end
```

Running this will give you the following output:

```
>> test
Variables are: a b 
Variables are: a b c d varNames
```

Comment: @Amro: I think it is. "I need to print out the variable_name**s** (in case of an exception etc.)." It sounds to me like they want to list the variables present after an exception occurs. The interpretation everyone else has made doesn't make much sense, since if the OP already knew which variable caused the exception, then they already knew its name and wouldn't have to get it from anywhere.

Comment: I agree that the OP's request is a bit strange (if you want to get a variable name as a string, then you already know it as you are typing the code!). The only use case I can think of this is to simplify error reporting or debugging. Perhaps this can be considered some sort of reflection capability...