# Matlab get string containing variable name

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, how can i get a String containing `"GRUMPY"` given the following declaration:

```
  GRUMPY = 500;
```

This is usually called reflection in other programming languages, but i cannot find an example of it in Matlab.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

MATLAB doesn't provide built-in functionality for this, but there is a workaround, as employed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6682015/38281)

Essentially, you have to create your own function to do this. Take advantage of Matlab's functionality for getting the variable name of the INPUT ARGUMENT to a function.

I.e.

```
function out = varname(var)
  out = inputname(1);
end
```

Then

```
GRUMPY = 500;
name = varname(GRUMPY)
```

will give you what you want.

Comment: That's nice! I didn't hear about `inputname` before. I would do it with using anonymous functions for this case though: `varname = @(x) inputname(1)`

Comment: @drodbar Agreed, assuming it works (don't have Matlab available right now). Of course, if you want to have this function available across all of your Matlab stuff, then you need a function-file residing in your path with this non-anonymous function.

Comment: This will fail if `var`  is anything but an object name.  For example,  `varname(foo.bar)`  will return an empty string.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft You can use `fieldnames` for structures.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you should try

```
who GRUMPY
```

or

```
which GRUMPY
```

Comment: Neither of these produce a string. See class(who GRUMPY)