# Getting variable name

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a scatter plot, labeling the x-axis using the variable name.

I tried using the R command to get the variable name of the dataset variable:

```
name(dsExample.Variable)
```

but that doesn't work.

I tried the code given in another stackoverflow question
[Matlab get string containing variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453165/matlab-get-string-containing-variable-name)

but I got a blank answer. Maybe it is due to using a dataset instead of a matrix, but then I tried converting the dataset variable using double() as the input.

What should I try next?

Comment: Could you use `dsExample.Properties.VarNames`?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the variable names in a data set using the `get` method:

```
data = rand(1000,2);
d = dataset({data, 'Random'});

scatter(data(:,1), data(:,2));
xlabel( get(d,'VarName') );
```

Comment: I tried `get(ds.Var1, 'VarName')` but I got an error saying _Error using handle.handle/get. Invalid or deleted object._

Comment: @Castielle, I believe the syntax is `get(ds,'VarName')` not `get(ds.Var1,'VarName')`