# Convert variable name to string in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

So say I have variables with variable names like SWCF and LWCF. Is there a way that I can convert these variable names into strings? I'd like to do this so that I can run functions on the variables - and have the plot titles include the variable name.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11453337/38281

Comment: I think it is - thanks so much! I'll try that out later today.

Answer (score 1):

their *names* are already of class `char`. For example if you clear all and dont have any variable in memory:

```
 SWCF = rand(10)
 a = whos
 a(1).name
```

so you can use `title(a(1).name)` in your plot etc...

Comment: Hmm - good idea. But is there a way to perform this without using a = whos? It would be difficult to do if SWCF could be the 1st variable in some cases, and the 10th variable in other cases.

Comment: @InquilineKea Perhaps you could replace `a = whos` by something like `a = whos('*CF')` to restrict the result. You can also use `[names{1:length(a)}] = deal(a.name)` to create a cell array with the names, which will be in alphabetical order.