# name of a variable in legend, matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, legend, legend-properties

I want the name of my variables in a plot legend in matlab. Is this possible?

my example is:

```
function example(x1)
    figure;
    plot(x1.time, x1.value);
    legend(x1);
end
```

---

now I want to call my function like:

```
>> example(myvariable)
```

my legend should look like:

```
---------------
| -- myvariable |
---------------
```

thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab get string containing variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453165/matlab-get-string-containing-variable-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`inputname`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html) to get the name of the input in the calling workspace and then pass this to `legend` or set the `DisplayName` property of the plot to this value.

```
function example(x1)
    figure
    plot(x1.time, x1.value)
    legend(inputname(1))
end
```