# Get object handle given the name as a string (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, simulink, handle

Being given the name of a variable as a string (in my case the name of an existing Simulink.Parameter variable in the workspace selected by the user as a design variable for optimization), I would like to be able to access the properties of the object such as Simulink.Parameter.Min, Simulink.Parameter.Max, Simulink.Parameter.Value **without using eval()**. So far I am employing the (very ugly) solution

```
varnames = {'var1','var2'}; % Simulink.Parameter objects existing in workspace
objects = cell(length(varnames),1);
for i = 1:length(varnames)
    eval(['objects{i}=', varnames{i}, ';']) % Store objects in a cell array
end
```

Ideally, this would look like:

```
objects = get_object_handles_from_string(varnames);
value_1 = object{1}.Value(:);
```

*Otherwise a method returning the variable name given the object handle would also be acceptable.*

Methods that I found not to be working but might be useful otherwise:

- [whos](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html) finds variable names and properties in the current workspace but no handles.
- [inputname](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html) returns the variable name of an explicit function input as a string but does not work for cell arrays of objects (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11453337/8751939)).
- [str2func](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) returns a function handle with a string as input but does not enable access to attributes.
- [findobj](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.findobj.html) returns objects given an array of objects to iterate over which I do not have. Might there be a method returning all workspace variable handles as an array?

Thanks!

Comment: `object{1}.(varnames{i})` works for you?

Comment: `varnames` refers to the name of the object itself, not the field name so it does not work. Firstly I have to get to the point where I store the pointers to my objects in a cell which I am using `eval` for at the moment (see original post).

Comment: Question: why are you starting from "being given the name of a variable as a string"? Is there no other way of getting it?

Comment: I want the user to input either the name of the variable or the variable itself, but not both, so one thing has to be derived from the other

Comment: There is missing information. What user? I am asking because you seem to be asking about a, attampted solution of something that is not really your problem, the classic XY problem. Having a software that gets strings from users to generate new variables is a very bad idea.

Comment: The purpose is to select already existing design variables for a following optimization procedure from the workspace with different names which I want to easily access in a cell array.

Comment: If the variables exist, and you give the user a list, why don;t you grab the index on that list that the user checks, instead of the variable name? That way you dont need to do any fancy/werid thing with strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what `eval` is for. Yes, you should avoid using `eval`, but if you want to have a user type in stuff to be evaluated, you need `eval`. [Or `evalin` if you want to evaluate it in the base or caller workspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html) rather than the current workspace.

There are no such thing as "object handles" (except graphics objects, but that is not what you are talking about here). There are variables owning arrays of data, that is it.

If you don't trust your users, don't use `eval`. They could type in anything, including `clear all` or `!\rm -rf /*` (or whatever the Windows equivalent is to erase the disk).

In this case, and presuming there is a limited set of variables that the user can specify, do

```
var1 = 1;
var2 = 2;
varnames = {'var1','var2'}; % Simulink.Parameter objects existing in workspace
objects = cell(size(varnames));
for i = 1:numel(varnames)
    objects{i} = get_variable_value(varnames{i}) % Store objects in a cell array
end

function val = get_variable_value(name)
   switch name
      case 'var1'
         val = evalin('caller',var1);
      case 'var2'
         val = evalin('caller',var2);
      otherwise
         error('Illegal variable name')
end
```