# how to convert a variable to string in matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, data-structures, struct

I have structure array

```
some_struct_var=struct( 'filed1', filed1, 'filed2', filed2 ,...)
```

I want to create a string

```
   str=['The struct variable name is :' , some_struct_var]
```

with the name of the structure variable in it. The some_struct_var may vary and is not fixed.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6681798/395857

Answer (score 3):

Create a function that takes any variable as an input and returns the string equivalent of that variable's name as an ouput like so:

```
varToStr = @(x) inputname(1);
structVarString = varToStr(some_struct_var)
str = ['The struct variable name is :', structVarString]
```