# Print the name of a variable on upon a plot/figure

Tags: matlab, text, graph, plot, matlab-figure

Is it possible to refer back to/access the names of variables (say nx1 arrays) that make up a matrix? I wish to access them to insert there names into a plot or figure (as a `text`) that I have created. Here is an example:

```
A = [supdamp, clgvlv,redamp,extfanstat,htgvlv,occupied,supfanspd]

%lots of code here but not changing A, just using A(:,:)'s

%drawn figure

text(1,1,'supdamp')
...
text(1,n,'supfanspd')
```

I have failed in an attempt create a string named `a` with their names in so that I could loop through `a(i,1)`, then use something like `text(1,n,'a(i,1)')`

Comment: A = {'supdamp', 'clgvlv','redamp','extfansta','htgvlv','occupied','supfanspd'} and acess through A{i}

Comment: Have you checked [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681798/print-variable-name-in-matlab) question

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro - Thank you, this does work. However I wish, eventually, to make it more autonomous so I cannot afford to re-write {'supdamp',...,'supfanspd'} or insert ''.

Comment: @Kamtal - I have attempted implementing this but I have not used functions much before and struggled to implement it. If I do not find another solution (as there normally are in MATLAB) I shall give it a second crack. Thank you both.

Comment: I do not get what you mean. if you defined them on code, then you can loop over them as explained. if you are reading from a text file or other that is a different problem. Please clarify exactly what you want

Comment: Sorry, I can see that wasn't too clear. Basically I have about 30 variables imported, 10 of which I wish to plot and name on a figure at any one. In order to plot them I have to type the variable names into `A = [supdamp,...,supfanspd]`where `A` contains data is referred to elsewhere in my code. So I didn't want to write out some new `B={'supdamp',...,'supfanspd'}` but just automatically have the names reffered to in each `text(x,y,'_')` function or the names inserted into the figure. Thanks.

Comment: How are you importing the files? It would be better to tackle this as the import stage by not making 30 different named variables in the first place.

Comment: just a standard MATLAB import function: 
`[supdamp,..,supfanspd] = importfile1('MassImportAHU7.csv');`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your problem, it might make sense to use [structures](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) with [dynamical field names](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/). 
Especially if your data in the array have some meaning other than just entries of a matrix in linear algebra sense.

```
# name your variables so that your grandma could understand what they store
A.('supdamp') = supdamp
A.('clgvlv') = clgvlv
... 

fieldsOfA = fieldnames(a)
for n = 1 : numel(fieldsOfA )
    text(1, n, fieldsOfA{n})
end
```