# MATLAB: create a string array with a list of variable names with a given prefix

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, variables, input

I would like to store the names of some variables in my workspace into a string array given a prefix. In particular, I have 'Xaws1', 'Xaws2', 'Xaws3' variables other than others in my workspace, and I want their names to populate an array which would look something like {'Xaws1', 'Xaws2', 'Xaws3'}.
In my case all the variable names have the same length (5 characters), and I'd like to find them using a prefix like "Xaws*". I tried with `who('Xaws*)`, but the output seems not usable in this sense. I also looked into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681798/print-variable-name-in-matlab/6682015#6682015), but could not find a solution so far.
Any idea would be very appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this is the opposite of what you are asking, but it probably still applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099398/create-variables-with-names-from-strings/16099569#16099569 your variables should probably rather be a cell array... have a look at the link in the comments of the question I linked to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `whos('Xaws*')`, you just need to extract the `name` field afterwards:

```
vars = whos('Xaws*');
names = {vars.name}
```

However, I strongly suggest that you don't have a bunch of variables named `Xaws?` where `?` is incrementing numbers. Rather use a cell array such that

```
Xaws{1} = Xaws1;
Xaws{2} = Xaws2;
etc...
```

Comment: Why not just `vars = whos('Xaws*')`? What does `'name'` mean here?

Comment: @LuisMendo I didn't know you could do that. the `'name'` just extracts the `name` field as a cell array... edited to use `*` instead

Comment: @Dan Weird. `whos('name')` doesn't work for me (it just looks for variables called `'name'`)